# Win32Com Python use one global Dispatcher instance to create multiple workbook objects in Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, win32com, pythoncom

Heres the code of what im trying to implement

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json   
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = None
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/check", methods=['POST'])
def check():

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        fname = data['fname']
        phName = data['PH_Name']
        liName = data['LI_NAME']
        ppm = data['PPM']
        policyTerm = data['Policy_Term']
        sumAssured = data['Sum_Assured']


        wb = None

        if xl : 
            wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fname) 


            inp_sheet = wb.Sheets["Inputs"]

            #read data from sheet
            data = inp_sheet.Range('D8').Value


            wb.Close(False)
            xl.Quit()
            return (data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, port=5001, debug=True)
```

The issue is that win32com creates new threads whenever a flask function is used to open a workbook and thus requires to marshal the Dispatcher object onto a stream to pass it to the function. 
How do i do that for an api call ?

I found some suggestions using CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream and CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream but they fail to run when multiple parallel calls are made to the api.